# Why PlotStyle->Dashed make everything dashed?

Tags: plotting, bugs, linux

**Bug introduced in 10.0.1 and fixed in 10.0.2** -- appears to affect Linux only.

---

It has been really strange for me. I am not sure it's regression after v10.0.1, or something went wrong with my system. After running this simple code

```
b = Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Dashed]
```

my Mathematica window becomes

[image]

**Edit:**

(1) Just re-installed v9.0.1, there is no such problem on v9.0.1. So it is regression.

(2) Seen from comments/answers, Windows and Mac do not have this problem, but problem under Linux is confirmed.

(3) The problem is already in `Graphics` (which is more fundamental). For example,

```
Graphics[{Dashed, Circle[]}]
```

has the same problem.

Comment: I don't notice this on **Windows**, so it's probably a system dependent bug.

Comment: No problem on windows using 10.01, screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JPoSW.png)

Comment: No problem on Mac. weird bug.

Comment: The same problem in Ubuntu + 10.0.1 . Moreover, no such behavior observed in 10.0. Seriously, this is not user-friendly.

Comment: That sure is a bizarre one.  I removed the version tag and added a header in accordance with [(1364)](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1364/121)

Comment: @YiWang Did Wolfram confirm the bug? Could they reproduce it?

Comment: @halirutan confirmed that it was reproducible on our end, and I believe a fix is in the next version.

Comment: Indeed, it's fixed in 10.0.2. Finally I don't have to reopen the files in M9 to make plots :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am having a same problem on Linux, Mathematica 10.0.01.
My "solution" (if you are looking for it?) for dashing of the frame was to specify each frame part individually:

```
b = Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True,
   FrameStyle -> {{Dashing[1], Dashing[1]}, {Dashing[1], Dashing[1]}}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image]

Very annoyingly, if I try to do the same trick to fill plot lines, one of them gets "cut"

```
b = Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True,
   FrameStyle -> {{Dashing[1], Dashing[1]}, {Dashing[1], Dashing[1]}},
   PlotStyle -> {Dashing[1], Dashing[1]}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, thanks! On my computer this option can be simplified into `FrameStyle -> Dashing[1]`. Also, if you specify `PlotStyle->Dashing[2]`, you will not get cut. I think the cut is actually the dashing :)

Comment: Also note that solid line means `Dashing[{}]`, so had better not use `Dashing[1]` or `Dashing[2]` (otherwise it cuts after the line is long enough).

Answer (score 6):

I'm expanding my comment to show I get the same problem, on V10.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I can also repeat it like this:

```
b = Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

And you can see the dashing in the cells down the right-hand side, as well as the dashed frame.

[image]

What is then **weirder** is if you click on the graph, this happens:

[image]

The line that was solid is now dashed too!

Comment: Thanks for confirmation! Has reported bug to Wolfram.

Comment: Yes, also, if you remove/fold the plot, then fold mathematica window, switch to another window and unfold it back again, the dashes disappear, unless you unfold the plot.